# Android Marshmallow permisions from Application class

Tags: android, permissions, request, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am integrating a third party sdk which is initiate from application class. But testing on Android Marshmallow API 23, I am getting permissions error as SDK required "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" permission.

As I need to integrated SDK on Application level not on Activity level, when I a calling

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1 );
```

IDE is giving error as "this" is not an Activity.

Is it possible to request Android permissions from Application class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, `PackageManager.buildRequestPermissionsIntent(...)` is only exposed via `Acitivty.requestPermissions(...)` currently, so you wouldn't even be able to launch the system window to request permissions from anywhere outside of an Activity.

The library is going to have to change (or you will have to catch the `SecurityException` :( ).

Comment: This is sad. Even new features are not being made correctly! Only shows that Google has worst devs.